# How to obtain from a musical score the different pentagrams(openCV)

Tags: c++, opencv, object-recognition

For the detection and processing of a picture of a score and then of each of the staves, I proceed as follows:

I take the picture and we stay with the horizontal components to stay alone with the lines of the staff, we eliminate the unnecessary components and noise and we mark the lines with HoughLinesP we verify that the lines are parallel to each other to subsequently relate by crop the different cuts to obtain the different staves of the imgen.

Finally my question is, do you think of some other simpler way, or more accurate for the detection and separation of the different pentagrams?

Attached image so you can see how it would be once processed for further cutting.

Now i need to obtain de diferent pentagrams.
[image pre processing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6hsw.jpg)

[image post processing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mY47S.png)

```
int offset_x = 50;
int offset_y = 50;

cv::Rect roi;
roi.x = offset_x;
roi.y = offset_y;
roi.width = horizontal.size().width - (offset_x * 2);
roi.height = horizontal.size().height - (offset_y * 2);

cv::Mat crop = horizontal(roi);
namedWindow("crop", WINDOW_NORMAL);
cv::imshow("crop", crop);
cv::waitKey(0);


//Use HougLines to detect de diferents lines of each pentagram
HoughLinesP(crop, lines, 1, CV_PI / 180, 80, 200, 10);

//We paint it
for (size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) // Draw the lines
{

    line(crop, Point(lines[i][0], lines[i][1]),Point(lines[i][2], lines[i][3]), Scalar(255, 255, 255), 3, 3);
}


// the final result

namedWindow("Detected Lines", WINDOW_NORMAL);
imshow("Detected Lines", crop);


waitKey(0);
```

Now I need to take out the different staves in order to extract them from the initial image. But I can not think of how to do it ....

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial that does exactly what your first algorithm does: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/dd/dd7/tutorial_morph_lines_detection.html
I can imagine that it is a little bit simpler than your approach. Also, the opposite case is shown in the example where you only keep your scores and refine them, supposedly what you want to do.